# What is the term for navigation options on the home page?

Tags: navigation, terminology

I'm having trouble Googling for information on my topic because I can't think of the correct term, so I'm turning here for terminology help.

What is the term for navigation options on the home page of the site? Not a menu on the top / side of the webpage, but something like big buttons or images that links to major sections of the site?

Comment: It may be better to say why your googling then you could have 2 answers in one.

Comment: @Marc- a navbar and sitemap are both small and inconspicuous. I'm thinking more of big navigation options that take up a significant portion of the screen

Comment: Got a sample you could show us? I don't think there's a standard term for a big "click here to go to section X" type thing.

Comment: @Marc: [this](http://www.interiors.davroc.co.uk) is an example of what I mean

Comment: I can't think of "standard" name for them. "big links" "top level section links"? They're just "click here to go to section X" offerings. Technically it'd be a menu of choices, that just happen to be extra large.

Answer (score 1):

Like the ones used on this site?

[image: Navigation Buttons]

I would just call those "Navigation Buttons" or a "Navigation Bar".  Googling for either term returns a lot of relevant results.  They're often implemented using a styled list of links, similar to how navigation menus are created (view the source on this page and search for `div class="nav mainnavs"` to see an example).